# How to add value into existing array without replacing exists array data?

Tags: php, laravel

Here I'm trying to book a seat if I book new seat existing seat will be replaced so how can I insert new data with an existing data in an array, for example seat ["A1"] already booked so if I book a new seat like ["B1"] need to store that data also into that array without update existing data or replace data. It is possible?

for example seat ["A1"] already booked so if I book a new seat like ["B1"] need to store that data also into that array.

here is the code for insert data

```
$booking = Bookings::updateOrCreate(
        ['schedules_id' => $schedules_id], // match the row based on this array
        [ // update this columns
        'buses_id' => $buses_id,
        'routes_id' => $routes_id,
        'seat' => json_encode($seat),
        'price' => $request->price,
        'profile' => 'pending',
    ]

);
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to update existing information or do you want to insert a brand new row?

Comment: What is the error given? What seems to be the problem? You are using everything correctly from what I can see

Comment: @Dylan for example seat ["A1"] already booked so if I book a new seat like ["B1"] need to store that data also into that array it possible?

Comment: @Charlie I need to add new data with existing without update existing data or replace